# Sharing a word in Android

Tags: java, android, textselection

I wanted to know if there is any feature in Android where I could select a word from a third party application and send or share that word to my application. I could store that word in my application for further processing.

Comment: you mean something like copy and paste?

Comment: yes, whenever I select a word in any app it is showing me the copy/paste option , but it is not showing me any share option from where I could share the word to my app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Implementing a "share" action is easiest if you are targeting API level 14+ (Android 4.0), as documented here: [Adding an Easy Share Action](http://developer.android.com/training/sharing/shareaction.html).

If you need to target an earlier API level, the process is a bit more involved, as documented here: [Receiving Content from Other Apps](http://developer.android.com/training/sharing/receive.html).

(Note that while I normally consider link-only answers on Stack Overflow to be a poor choice, the process of implementing "share" actions is somewhat involved and fully documented on the Android developer site.  This is a case where simply pointing you at the documentation seems like the most appropriate thing to do.)

Answer (score 0):

Here is Android copy/paste desciption: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/text/copy-paste.html.
But I don't think there is way to modify 3rd-party app's context menu to add custom option like share, without changing this app's source code or changing Android platform (to add your own sharing mechanism to context menu).